# sqoop imports to a different directory than the Hive warehouse directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

When I use `sqoop` to import tables into Hive the tables go to a different directory than `/user/hive/warehouse` in HDFS Hadoop. I'm using a default Derby database for the Hive metastore. How can I change this directory to the Hive warehouse directory by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--hive-home /user/hive/warehouse`. Generally when you are importing data from relational database `hive-home` has to be selected by default. As you're mentioning that it is not using the warehouse path try setting the parameter using `--hive-home`.